# Ajax request stuck in Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, macos, safari

I' am uploading files directly to `Amazon S3` using their Multipart way of uploading files via `Ajax` request. Everything is working fine but sometimes `Ajax` request gets stuck in Safari on Mac. The issue is just weird because it is not happening in any other Browser on any Platform but Safari on Mac is creating problems.

`Ajax` request gets completely stuck and not even getting timed out.

Any help / hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you set a timeout on the request?

Comment: is `async` `true` or `false` for the ajax request?

Comment: @RayNicholus I cannot set timeout on request because I' am uploading file using `Ajax` request and it don't seems appropriate to set timeout on `Ajax` request because I think setting timeout on `Ajax` request means that if request completes within time limit then it's fine else terminate request.

Comment: @celeriko `async` is set to `true`.

Comment: @ImranLatif You are correct, timeout isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Same problem here. @ImranLatif, you have solve the problem?

Comment: @ptCoder I added a `setTimeout` function to be triggered after 40 seconds in Ajax request progress event. I' am clearing previously defined callback and setting a new one each time progress event is triggered. If progress event is not triggered for good 40 seconds the callback will abort the request and sends the request again. This was the only solution that I found. It might gives users some stucking progress experience but it is better than getting stucked there forever.